# how to prevent water leaking to basement

Tags: bathroom, water, tile, leak

Bought my first house.

some water was spelled in the bathroom,
but i found that it is dripping in the basement.

is there anything I can do to protect the basement from future leaking

do I have to remove tiles and add some protective sheets or there is some easier solution for that?

Comment: The important thing is to keep the water where it belongs. "Protective sheets" and so forth just divert the water to another place it isn't supposed to be.

Comment: You need to first find out where the water is coming from. Fixing a leaking pipe is very different from condensation from a rising water table from a cracked drain tile, etc etc

Comment: The amount of water would be handy to know.  Tile floor should hold a cup easy, 5 gallons would be much different.

Answer (score 2):

First, use silicone caulk. Caulk every place where your tile floor comes in contact with another material. Where your walls meet the floor, where the toilet meets the floor, where your tub meets the floor, you get the idea.

Also caulk all areas that hold water, especially your shower/bath, and look for places where water might escape from them and splash onto walls/floor. Make sure walls are protected with appropriate paint or material, and that water splashes are diverted away (like with shower curtains, etc.

Make sure the bathroom is well ventilated.

Check the spots where pipes go through the walls and floors and seal any gaps with spray foam/flanges.

Make sure your grout is in good repair, fill any gaps and consider a grout sealer.

Properly applying high quality silicone caulk is definitely your best bet for an easy solution.

Water splashes around a lot in bathrooms, that’s hard to avoid (especially with kids!). But it’s not hard to keep it out of the basement with a little diligence. Watch the water and figure out it’s escape paths, seal them up so it can be wiped up or evaporate while still on non-porous surfaces.

Good luck with your new house!